# How can I uninstall HPQC 11 Client?

Tags: quality-center

Simple question. The answer from the Official Installation Guide:

> Go to http://h20230.www2.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM176290 and
>   download a tool for uninstalling

(nice). Going there (right now) and (okay, must authorize me once more) seeing kind of 404-Error or "please contact your local dealer or support".

**Motivation**

Now a few words about the reason *why* I want to uninstall, it may be helpful for others.

1. At first I've downloaded the GERMAN localization of HPQC 11. Okay, was not much fun, but really good localizations are rare, no problem.
2. Tried to switch Project Language to English - no such feature available. Still no problem.
3. Uninstall everything (server-side), install EN-Version from scratch. My old-test project still there (did I wanted it?) - never mind, must be a feature.
4. Opening client software, client interface still in German - hm, my old project is still perfectly non-perfect German. Never mind, I am evaluating.
5. So just for fun, another computer on, client installing on it. The new project (hopefully in English) created. The new project is in the new PC real English (yahoo!), the old project is mixed, client interface in English, but some nuts (e.g. Defects Columns) are still German. Okay, no problem, if you knew it. So deleted the old project, back to my PC, started old German client with the new English project. Oops, not only mixture from German/English, but also errors at opening... No good... So I need to uninstall the client an install it from beginning. And back there are we.

Long life the QA. And usability.

Comment: Alexei, I removed the "off-topic" part of the question.  It did not seem relevant to the rest.

Comment: okay, no problem, was just bragging :-D

Comment: Alexei, what type of OS did you install it on?  Is it possible to do a System Restore?  Is it possible for you to create a Virtual Machine to install it on?

Comment: Windows 7, Virtual Machines or System Restores are not welcome :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software installs. Better asked on http://superuser.com

Comment: Alexei, here's working link: https://softwaresupport.hp.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM176290

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the computer?

If you can't manage to clean it far enough to reinstall this piece of software in a different language and you do not want to use a Virtual machine for evaluation. I don't see any other short term solution.

Since this questions is already so old I voted to close it, because it does not make any sense anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Alexei, here's the working link: https://softwaresupport.hp.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM176290